# Get all result for all indexes of a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a List of object type. I want to get all results from this list having indexes equal to values present in another list of type integer. This is what I have tried:

`intList` - List of integers
`result` - List of object type
`strList` - List of object type

```
intList.ForEach(iInt =>
  { strList.Add(result.ElementAt(iInt).ToString()); }
);
```

Is this possible without using foreach i.e. in single lambda expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This LINQ expression is equivalent to your `ForEach` statement (assuming `strList` was initially empty):

```
strList = intList.Select(i => result.ElementAt(i).ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Do note that the `foreach()` is just hidden in the `ToList()` now.

Answer (score 1):

The last line is a desired lambda:

```
var strings = new [] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
var ints = new [] { 2, 4};
var result = ints.Select(i=>strings[i]); // returns "three", "five"
```